# "Ясли-сад" предложном падеже - ?

Tags: орфография

Как будет выглядеть слово "ясли-сад" в предложном падеже - "в одном из (ясли-сад)"?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как будет выглядеть слово "ясли-сад" в
> предложном падеже - "в одном из
> (ясли-сад)"?

*...в одн**их** из [московских] яслей-садов*

или

*...в эт**их** яслях-саду.*

См. https://books.google.ru/books?id=STRqAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA397&dq=%22%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=9AwLVZfNKsH8ygOKqYGwCA&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%22&f=false :

> *В сочетаниях с приложениями согласование происходит с первым
> существительным: **новых**
> яслей-сада…*

===============================

Как вариант:

***...в одном из детских дошкольных учреждений.***

Comment: Ну да, согласна, как его ни назови - сложное сущ. или приложение.При согласовании со сложными существительными, образующими сложносоставные термины типа кафе-столовая, учитываются смысловые отношения между частями сложного слова:ведущим компонентом, с которым согласуется сказуемое, является то слово, которое выражает более широкое понятие или конкретно обозначает предмет.В существительном "ясли-сад" обе части по смыслу равноправны, согласование идет с ближайшей частью слова.

Answer (score 3):

Только не предложный, а родительный: В одном из (чего? каких учреждений?) детских садов-яслей. Или: в одних из яслей-садов.

Такая форма возможна, но лучше вариант Сержа - в яслях-саду.

Comment: В одних из..., в одном из... - конструкция словосочетания со сложным словом, написанным через дефис, сложная для слуха, лучше обойтись более коротким и простым.

Comment: Причина "корявости" рассматриваемого нами сочетания кроется всё же не в наличии дефиса у слова "ясли-сад": к примеру, "в одном из вагонов-ресторанов" никаких нареканий, наверное, ни у кого бы  не вызвало. "Виновата" (помимо несовпадения грамматического рода у частей этого слова) в немалой степени и сама форма мн. ч. у слова "ясли". 

По-моему, и "в одних из яслей" (применительно к какому-то одному из этих учреждений, а не к некоторому их множеству) тоже звучит не очень здорово.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: В яслях-саду.